# How to handle ValidationError, which are throwed by the class-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting following response if I send invalid data:

```js
{
  "name": "BadRequestError",
  "message": "Invalid body, check 'details' property for more info.",
  "stack": "Error\n at BadRequestError.HttpError [as constructor] (",
  "httpCode": 400,
  "details":[
    {
      "target":{…},
      "value": "abc",
      "property": "email",
      "children":[],
      "constraints":{"isEmail": "email must be an email"}
    }
  ]
}
```

and i need the validation result in the following structure:

```js
{
  "ValidationErrors": [
    {
      "target":{…},
      "value": "abc",
      "property": "email",
      "children":[],
      "constraints":{"isEmail": "email must be an email"}
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: why do you need it rewritten?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that pretty easily with the spread operator. I'm not exactly sure if you want it stored in a variable or what but here's how you can get it in that format. I'm guessing that response is JSON.

```js
data = {
  "name": "BadRequestError",
  "message": "Invalid body, check 'details' property for more info.",
  "stack": "Error\n at BadRequestError.HttpError [as constructor] (",
  "httpCode": 400,
  "details":[
    {
      "target":{…},
      "value": "abc",
      "property": "email",
      "children":[],
      "constraints":{"isEmail": "email must be an email"}
    }
  ]
}

const response = JSON.parse(data);

const validationErrors = { ValidationErrors: [ ...response.details ] }

console.log(validationErrors);
```

it is a javascript object at this point and not JSON

```
{
  ValidationErrors: [
    {
      "target":{…},
      "value": "abc",
      "property": "email",
      "children":[],
      "constraints":{isEmail: "email must be an email"}
    }
  ]
}
```